# How to pass data between ejs/static page to node express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a node app to display webviews for facebook messenger, using ejs templates and express.

1.) How to pass data from node to the "frontend"/client?
-until now I am doing that using res.render('index', {key: value});
is there another way?

2.) How to pass data from the client to the backend.
-I used /post when i had a form but what if i dont have a form, as an example i will get the facebook id of the user in a async way on the frontend and want to transmit it to the backend.

Comment: Ans 2. [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)

Answer (score 1):

I have recently been using a p5.js library. It has a method called loadJSON() to get data from the backend node app. And for post i just use httpPost() method, I invoke it in the function once a button was clicked e.g.

It's a nice library tough suggesting you using the minified version.